# TCP communication fails when connected to Xamarin.Android with C# code via Wi-Fi in Android 13 (API Level 33) environment

Tags: c#, android, tcp, wifi

There was a problem communicating TCP from Android 13 (API Level 33) to Xamarin.Android environment after desired Wi-Fi connection via SSID and Password to C#.

If you connect the Wi-Fi through the code, the TCP server side will ping the android, but if you ping the TCP server from the android, it will not connect.

But if you connect Wi-Fi directly from Android and ping TCP server from Android, it works fine and also connects well with server.

**WifiConnector.cs**

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Net.Wifi;
using Android.Net;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(RemoteAGV.Droid.WifiConnector))]

namespace RemoteAGV.Droid
{
    public class WifiConnector : IWifiConnector
    {
        Context context;
        WifiManager wifiManager;
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;

        public WifiConnector()
        {
            context = Android.App.Application.Context;
            wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
            connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
        }

        public void ConnectToWifi(string ssid, string password)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Q)
            {
                NetworkSpecifier specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                    .SetSsid(ssid)
                    .SetWpa2Passphrase(password)
                    .Build();

                NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                    .AddTransportType(Android.Net.TransportType.Wifi)
                    .SetNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
                    .Build();

                ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback callback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback();
                connectivityManager.RequestNetwork(request, callback);

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, "FALSE", ToastLength.Short).Show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**COMM.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace RemoteAGV
{
    static public class COMM
    {
        static private TcpClient m_TcpClient = null;
        static NetworkStream m_ClientStream = null;

        static public Byte[] m_WriteBuffer = new Byte[10];
       
        /*  MOVE(Control Page)
             //header(0~2)
             * byte[0] = 60; //<
             * byte[1] = 83; //S
             * byte[2] = 62; //>
             * 
             * byte[3] = mode ->  0 = 일반  1 = QD
             * byte[4] = linear velocity 선속도 0.1 ~ 1.8  (value : * 10)
             * byte[5] = angular velocity 각속도 5 ~ 30
             * byte[6] = direction button
             * byte[7] = Exclusive OR //데이터 정합성
             * 
        */

        static public bool Connect()
        {
            m_TcpClient = new TcpClient();

            if (m_TcpClient.ConnectAsync("192.168.0.8", 8899).Wait(1000))  //test
            // 여기서 부터 TCP 연결이 안 됨   
            // if (m_TcpClient.ConnectAsync("10.10.100.254", 8899).Wait(200))
                    m_ClientStream = m_TcpClient.GetStream();
            else
                return false;           

            return true;
        }

        static public void Close()
        {
            if (m_ClientStream != null) m_ClientStream.Close();
            if (m_TcpClient != null) m_TcpClient.Close();
        }

        public static void ClearWriteBuffer()
        {
            Array.Clear(m_WriteBuffer, 0, m_WriteBuffer.Length);
        }

        public static bool WriteData()
        {
            try
            {
                if (m_TcpClient.Connected && m_ClientStream != null)
                {
                    m_ClientStream.Write(m_WriteBuffer, 0, m_WriteBuffer.Length);
                    m_ClientStream.Flush();
                }
            }

            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;           
        }

        public static void WriteEndData()
        {
            ClearWriteBuffer();

            Byte _BCC = 0;

            //head
            COMM.m_WriteBuffer[0] = 60; //<
            COMM.m_WriteBuffer[1] = 83; //S
            COMM.m_WriteBuffer[2] = 62; //>

            COMM.m_WriteBuffer[3] = 0;

            COMM.m_WriteBuffer[4] = 0;

            COMM.m_WriteBuffer[5] = 0;

            COMM.m_WriteBuffer[6] = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                _BCC ^= COMM.m_WriteBuffer[i];
            }
            COMM.m_WriteBuffer[7] = _BCC;

            WriteData();
        }     
    }    
}
```

I tried to do TCP communication after connecting Wi-Fi through code. However, I found that connecting Wi-Fi through code doesn't even send ping to TCP server. But if you connect directly to Wi-Fi, not code, it will connect well to TCP server.

Comment: I usually find issues like this are due to TCP using IPV6 instead of IPV4.